# Android Layout Relative to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

This is a bit simplified to make the question easier to ask.

I have a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. I'm not allowed to modify the LinearLayout but I would like to display a button to the right of each element in the LinearLayout. I tried looking at ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout, but I'm getting a message that since these are not siblings, this won't work.

How can I display a button to the right of a view when that view is inside a LinearLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--
    DO NOT MODIFY THIS SECTION!!!
-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:text="A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:text="B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:text="D"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!--
    END OF DO NOT MODIFY SECTION!!!
-->

<!--
    PLACE THIS BUTTON TO THE RIGHT OF BUTTON C
-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c_aux"
        android:text="C AUX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/c" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post the code you have tried.

Comment: Take RelativeLayout as root layout and make the view as toRightOf the Vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: That would align to the right of the linear layout, not the contained button.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to display a button to the right of a View, use the XML param **android:layout_toRightOf="@id/someIDhere"**. 
But remember, in order to use this parameter you need to declare and ID to the element that you are trying to use as the reference, You can do that by just adding this parameter in any view: **android:id="@+id/newname"**

here we use the + sign to denote that this is the first time that we are declaring the ID.

Comment: As I mentioned, I try this and I get an error that the someIDhere isn't a sibling, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another `LinearLayout` inside your main `LinearLayout`. The sub layout can have horizontal orientation.

Result:

[image]

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Button Left"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button Right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Button Bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not allowed to modify the LinearLayout, so this solution doesn't address the issue. :-(